# how to put a direct download link to songs in my music website

Tags: hyperlink

sir i have a website name www.sarigama.net. By this site i want to host songs regarding bollywood and all other indian  regional language movie songs in my site.recently i completed my website design in my laptop.But i don't know how to give a direct downlaod link to the songs.Sir please help me to give direct download link to the songs.please suggest some html codes regarding this problem.

Comment: Welcome to [su]! Please read [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic),  [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://superuser.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Copy the song files to a subdirectory under the main webpage directory. For example if your webpage is in `/var/www` then you can create a subdirectory called `songs`, therefore the full path will be `/var/www/songs`.

On the webpage you can create a download link like this :

`<a href="songs/songfile1.mp3">Song 1</a>`